# What size litter box do I get for my cat?

Tags: cats, cat-litter

What size litter box do I get for my cat?
People recommend:

> `at least 1.5 times the length of the cat`

> `at least 1.5 times longer than your cat`

1. **Which one is correct/better?**
   *the first* = `1.5L`
   *the second* = `L + 1.5L`
2. **What exactly is the length?**
   `Torso length`? `Torso-neck-head length`? `Tail-torso-neck-head length`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When it comes to litter boxes, **bigger is better.**

Bigger boxes mean:

- More clean surface area to use. (But you should still clean it just as frequently.)
- More room, so the cat will be less cramped and more comfortable.
- The cat will be less likely to kick litter out of it while digging.

The advice you're finding is surely more of a *minimum size.*  People give a minimum size requirement because of course humans tend to prefer litter boxes to be small. The minimum size is based on how much room does a cat need to turn around.

To more directly answer your questions, I take the two quotes to intend the same meaning, that is, 1.5 times the length of the cat, even if "1.5 times longer than the cat" may be a bit more ambiguous or confusing. Reading it to mean L + 1.5L would mean they recommend a litter box 2.5 times the length of the cat, which I think would be bigger than you're likely to find.

As to, what is included in the length of the cat, it is without the length of the tail, as the length of the body (including the head and neck) is what matters for allowing the cat enough room to turn around.

But, as I said, bigger is better, so if you're still feeling uncertain, just buy the biggest litter box you can.

Comment: Thank you, that totally answers all my questions very well. I will look for the biggest thing available. thanks for explaining it so well :)